# Contrapositive of: If $a$ is a real number such that $|a| < r$ for every positive real number $r$, then $a=0.$

Tags: propositional-calculus

I wish to state the contrapositive of:

> If $a$ is a real number such that $|a| < r$ for every positive real number $r$, then $a=0.$

First, I want to state the original statement symbolically.

> $\exists a \in \mathbb{R} (\forall r \in \mathbb{R}^+ (|a| < r \implies a = 0))$

Afterwards, we then can take the contrapositive:

> $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}(\exists r \in \mathbb{R}^+ (a \neq 0 \implies |a| \ge r))$

The thing I am most concerned about are the quantifiers of $a$. Please let me know what you think of my attempt.

Comment: The contrapositive is Ok, but why you have swapped the quantifiers?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Isn't that what I am supposed to do? Because $\forall a, P(a) \implies Q(a) \equiv \exists a, \neg Q(a) \implies \neg P(a)$

Comment: See [Contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition): the contrapositive of $P \to Q$ is $\lnot Q \to \lnot P$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Unfortunately, that's what I tried to do but the Wikipedia page doesn't cover quantifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have arrived at a common misconception.

The "If $a$ is a real number..." part (and variations thereof), are almost always equivalent to the phrasing (and variations thereof).

"Let $a$ be a real number..."

Then there is in fact no quantifier to change for that part and your statement becomes:

Let $a$ be a real number such that $|a|<r$ for every positive real number $r$, then $a=0$.

Then the contrapositive is:

If $a \neq 0$, then there exists a positive real number $r$ such that $|a| \geq r$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why there is no quantifier change?

Comment: It is simply a matter of phrasing in math that needs to be abolished for this very reason. All that is going on is this: If $a$ is a real number where $x \implies y$, the contrapositive is if $a$ is a real number not $y \implies$ not $x$.

Comment: But I don't understand. I was taught that when taking a contrapositive, I should negate the quantifiers as well. How can I know when to negate the quantifiers, and when not to?