# Contrapositive, Converse and Inverse of statements with multiple quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

My textbook only touched on negation of statements with multiple quantifiers, and I would like to know:

1. For a statement like

   $\forall M>0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that if $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ then $|f(x)| > M,$

   is its contrapositive

   $\forall M>0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that if ~$(|f(x)| > M)$ then  ~$(0 < |x-a| < \delta)\quad?$
2. Do the converse and inverse similarly just affect the if-else?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The contrapositive of $P \to Q$ is $\lnot Q \to \lnot P$ and the two are equivalent. Thus, you can exchange them **inside** the quantifiers and the result is equiv to the original formula. But this is **not** what you get when you negate the full formula with quantifiers.

Comment: The converse of $P \to Q$ is $Q \to P$ and it is **not** equivalent to the original one. Thus, you cannot exchange them without affecting the meaning and truth value of the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Contrapositive, Converse and Inverse all refer and apply to conditional formulae and affect only their antecedents and consequents and not any surrounding quantifier or connective.

This is not to say that they never alter quantifiers: the contrapositive of $$\forall x\big(Px\to\exists y Qxy\big)$$ is $$∀x(∀y¬Qxy→¬Px).$$ (Strictly speaking, we are referring to the contrapositive of the string within the parentheses.)

[How can I know when to negate quantifiers when taking the contrapositive of a statement?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4518680/21813)